# Finding largest and second-largest out of N numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, comparison, performance, runtime

Given n numbers, how do I find the largest and second largest number using at most n+log(n) comparisons?

Note that it's not O(n+log(n)), but really n+log(n) comparisons.

Comment: Do you want the actual algorithm, or a clue (ie. some kind of homework help)?

Comment: I'd like to see the actual algorithm. This is not homework, but a question from one of my co-workers.

Comment: This is called tournament selection algorithm. You can read more for instance here: http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=11556

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pajton gave a comment.

Let me elaborate.

As pajton said, this can be done by tournament selection.

Think of this as a knock out singles tennis tournament, where player abilities have a strict order and the outcome of a match is decided solely by that order.

In the first round half the people are eliminated. In the next round another half etc (with some byes possible).

Ultimately the winner is decided in the last and final round.

This can be viewed as a tree.

Each node of the tree will be the winner of the match between the children of that node.

The leaves are the players. The winner of the first round are the parents of the leaves etc.

This is a complete binary tree on n nodes.

Now follow the path of the winner. There are log n matches the winner has played. Now consider the losers of those log n matches. The second best must be the best among those.

The winner is decided in n-1 matches (you knock out one per match) and the winner among the logn is decided in logn -1 matches.

Thus you can decide the largest and second largest in n+logn - 2 compares.

In fact, it can proven that this is optimal. In any comparison scheme in the worst case, the winner would have to play logn matches.

To prove that assume a point system where after a match the winner gets the points of the loser. Initially all start out with 1 point each.

At the end the final winner has n points.

Now given any algorithm, it could be arranged so that player with more points is always the winner. Since the points of any person at most double in any match in that scenario, you require at least log n matches played by the winner in the worst case.

Comment: Heh, I didn't give an answer, because it was late and I was going to sleep:). You did a good job though!

Comment: @paj: Thanks! I was just curious and it was my way of acknowledging that you answered it first :-) I will delete that part.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem with this? It's at most 3n comparisons (not counting the `i < n` comparison). If you count that, it's 4n (or 5n in the second example).

```
double first = -1e300, second = -1e300;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
  if (a[i] > first){
    second = first;
    first = a[i];
  }
  else if (a[i] > second && a[i] < first){
    second = a[i];
  }
}
```

another way to code it:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if (a[i] > first) first = a[i];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if (a[i] < first && a[i] > second) second = a[i];
```

Comment: Yes, there is a problem: your solution uses more than n+log(n) comparisons on average. +1 for your effort.

Comment: @Philip: duh. I looked at the `+` and saw `*`.

Comment: `&& a[i] < first` this part is unnecessary as it's essence is covered in first if.

Comment: @user its there to avoid getting same values for `first` and `second`. For an array where largest element repeats, not having `&& a[i] < first` will cause both first and second to have same value