# How to find the second smallest element in  n + logn -2 comparisons?

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding largest and second-largest out of N numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691140/finding-largest-and-second-largest-out-of-n-numbers)

How to find the second smallest element from a give set of n elements in n + logn -2 comparisons ?

I have seen the similar questions but they don't provide efficient solution.

Comment: I have corrected the question. Actually it is n-logn -2 comparisons

Comment: ya it's same ....i m looking for same ...

Comment: The top answer to the question linked is n-logn-2, so still an exact duplicate.

Comment: i got the answer from the similar question. Can any one tell me how can   I close this question